# Match repeated 3 or more times

Tags: regex

### This a quiz exercise

I'd like to know if a text contains words with **4 characters or more** which are **repeated 3 or more times** in the text (anywhere in the text). If so, set one (and only one) backreference for each word.

I tried the code

```
(?=\b(\w{4,}+)\b.*\1)
```

Results returns

> Test 10/39: Not working, sorry. Read the task description again. It matches notword word word

Tried

```
(?=(\b\w{4,}\b)(?:.*\b\1\b){2,})
```

> Test 22/39: If a certain word is repeated many times, you're setting more than 1 backreference (common mistake, I know). You don't necessarily need to match the first occurrence of the word. Can you avoid a match in >word< word word word, and match word >word< word word? (Hint: match if it's followed by 2 occurences, don't match if it's followed by 3)

Regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/DP3mtt/7)

Comment: What programming language or tool do you use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this should do what you want:

```
(?=(\b\w{4,}\b)(?:.*\b\1\b){2})(?!(\b\w{4,}\b)(?:.*\b\1\b){3})
```

It is essentially the same as your regex, looking for a word of 4 characters that is repeated, but it looks for 2 extra occurrences (so it appears 3 times). The words which match will be captured in group 1. The regex includes a negative lookahead for 3 repeats, so that it won't match the same word twice if it occurs 4 or more times.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DP3mtt/9)

Comment: In the demo link it is only matching the words which appear 3 times, is that not what you want?

Comment: @LyuJH see my edit and updated demo. I added word breaks around the first group to ensure that it only matches whole words.

Comment: (?=(\b\w{4,}\b)(?:.*\b\1\b){2,}) showed that Test 22/39: If a certain word is repeated many times, you're setting more than 1 backreference (common mistake, I know). You don't necessarily need to match the first occurrence of the word. Can you avoid a match in >word< word word word, and match word >word< word word? (Hint: match if it's followed by 2 occurences, don't match if it's followed by 3)

Comment: @LyuJH see my edit. It includes a negative lookahead to avoid matching more than once if the word occurs more than 3 times.